# Completing information in the table Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I was hoping someone could help me with a part of the formula to get me to my end goal.

Table PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID:

[image]

Table LOG:

[image]

PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID table has order status per day, but when you turn the month, it loses information. A LOG table has one last transition of each request per day and it is this table that is the correct reference. I have to create a new table that shows me all the requests and their days without losing information as soon as the birthday turn-over happens.

Example:

[image]

NOTE: Notice that this is a small example. My database table has tens of thousands of values.

How to achieve the final result?

Table Log
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal. Is your example the desired output?

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: Can you post the LOG table in tabular form as appear in the Data view? (Preferably as text so people can copy and paste)

Comment: I added it in the question, it's a table I'm looking for in the database

Comment: Link to download the project:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=12UdxyL026MmAPYsoBU-IW0jfN7C-eQBP

PR_HIST_MOVIM_PEDID table has order status by day, but when you turn the month, it loses information. The LOG table has one last day of each request per day and this table is a correct reference. I have to create a new table that shows me all the requests and their days without losing the information as soon as the turn of the month happens.
I need to get the result that was shown in the sample image

Comment: I don't have permission to view the link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12UdxyL026MmAPYsoBU-IW0jfN7C-eQBP?usp=sharing I gave link access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a new table that just has the dates that you want to use. I created a new table like this:

```
AllDates = CALENDAR(MIN(TableLOG[DTH_INCLUI_LOG]), MAX(TableLOG[DTH_INCLUI_LOG]))
```

Now write a measure like this:

```
Measure = 
    VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE(AllDates[Date])
    VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX(TableLOG[DTH_INCLUI_LOG]),
                      TableLOG[DTH_INCLUI_LOG] <= CurrentDate)
    RETURN CALCULATE(MAX(TableLOG[VLR_NOVO]), TableLOG[DTH_INCLUI_LOG] = MaxDate)
```

You should now be able to create a matrix with the `AllDates[Date]` for the columns and the `Ovitem_log` for the rows with the `Measure` for the values.

Comment: Any results, my friend? I have already released access for you.

Comment: Uh, yes. Did you not see the answer you're replying to?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Could you help me with this solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232484/i-need-to-do-status-counts-every-day-on-power-bi