# I need to do status counts every day on power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a log table that shows me the order log per day. This table contains one measure and one column which are:

Column Date:

```js
AllDates = CALENDAR(MIN('LOG'[DTH_INCLUI_LOG]);MAX('LOG'[DTH_INCLUI_LOG]))
```

Measure LogStatus:

```js
VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE(AllDates[Date])
VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX('LOG'[DTH_INCLUI_LOG]);'LOG'[DTH_INCLUI_LOG] <= CurrentDate+1)
RETURN CALCULATE(MAX('LOG'[VLR_NOVO]); 'LOG'[DTH_INCLUI_LOG] = MaxDate)
```

This column and measure was this table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqPLW.png)
Now I need to create a new table that counts the amount of each status per day.
Example: On day one got 45 status A, 75 status P, 35 status Q (...)

How do I achieve this result?

Comment: Have you tried `COUNT`, `COUNTX`, or `COUNTROWS`?

Comment: Yes, the count occurred incorrectly. Well, I need to count the statuses by day. I emphasize that the statuses that are shown in the table are obtained through a measure

Comment: I tried to use several formulas, even adapted a measure that you developed, but I did not get results. Would you help me?